# Pass Selected values of ListBox to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms

i have many to many relationship between faxes and employees [image]

I wanna have a fax form which has a listBox to select employees but i don't know how get the selected employees

FaxForm.cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateFax", "Fax"))
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">


    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Fax.Courier_Num, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Fax.Courier_Num, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Fax.Courier_Num)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.ListBox("Employees", ViewBag.Employees as MultiSelectList,
            new { @class = "chzn-select", data_placeholder = "Choose Employee..." })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

FaxController.cs:

```
public ActionResult New()
    {
        var Employees = Db.Employees;
        ViewBag.Employees = new MultiSelectList(Employees, "Id", "Name");
        return View("FaxForm");

    }
    public ActionResult CreateFax(Fax fax)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
         //some Code
            return View("FaxForm"/*, viewModel*/);
        }


        if (fax.Id == 0)
        {
            Db.Faxes.Add(fax);
            Db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Employees");
    }
```

i create viewmodel class to make relation between employees and faxes 
MenuViewModel.cs:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Employees { set; get; }
    public Fax Fax { set; get; }
```

i need to save the selected employees in fax table..........................

Comment: how can i pass selected values to faxcontroller ?????

Comment: i have a model public class MenueViewModelcs
    {
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Employees { set; get; }
        public Fax Fax { set; get; }
       
        
    }

Comment: [edit] your question to include that comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a view model specific to your view. Do not mix your entity model with that.

```
public class SendFaxVm
{
    public List<SelectListItem> Employees { set; get; }
    public int[] SelectedEmployees { set; get; }

    public string CompanyName { set; get; }
    public string CompanyAddress { set; get; }
    // To do : Add other properties needed in the VIEW
}
```

Now in your GET action, create an object of this, load the Employees property and send it to the view

```
public ActionResult New()
{
   var vm= new SendFaxVm();
   vm.Employees = db.Employees
                    .Select(a => new SelectListItem() {Value = a.Id.ToString(),
                                                       Text = a.Name})
                    .ToList();
   return View(vm);
}
```

Now in your view, which is strongly typed to our SendFaxVm, use the helper methods to generate your textbox's and multi select dropdown

```
@model SendFaxVm
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateFax", "Fax"))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.CompanyName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.CompanyAddress)
    @Html.ListBoxFor(a => a.SelectedEmployees, Model.Employees)
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

And use the same view model as the parameter of your HttpPost action method. When the form is submitted the properties will be populated by the data sent from the form. The SelectedEmployees property will be an array of UserId's which was selected. You can read these property values and save it to your entity tables.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateFax(SendFaxVm model)
{
   // check model.SelectedEmployees and other properties
   //  and use that to save data to your tables
   Fax f=new Fax();
   f.CompanyName = model.CompanyName;
   f.CompanyAddress = model.CompanyAddress;
   // to do : Assign other property values for the Fax table
   db.Fax.Add(f); 
   db.SaveChanges();

   //Now loop through the SelectedEmployees and save record for FaxData table
   foreach(var userId in model.SelectedEmployees)
   {
       var fd=new FaxData { EmpId = userId, FaxId=f.Id };
       //to do  : Save fd 
   }

   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: I got error There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'SelectedEmployees'.

Comment: When are you getting the error ? When you load the form initially ? or when you submit. If it is the second case, i assume you have a `return View()` statement somewhere inside the `CreateFax` method. You need to repopulate the Employees property same as we did it in the GET action method before the `return View` statement.

Comment: when i debug your code i got var Employees = null !

Comment: i don't have error but there is no employeeId added to faxdata table

Comment: You have to replace `//to do  : Save fd` withe the code to save data to that table. (basically  to `db.FaxData(fd)` and `db.SaveChanges()`)

Comment: but with the same code it should make Fax f = the values but in debugging i have null

Comment: You have to save to 2 different table , one is Fax and once that is done, loop through the SelectedEmployees collection and save one record to the FaxData table for each item in SelectedEmployees.